# 64 bit VS2008 Post Build Event Command Line

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to use the post build command line to get my class library in the GAC.
It is:

```
"%programfiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64\gacutil.exe" -if $(TargetPath)
```

I do not see any errors, but my DLL is not getting into the GAC.
However, I can run this from a DOS prompt and it works.
Anything special I need to do to make this command work in VS like this?

Comment: Do you see the message "Assembly successfully added to the cache" after the build?  I'm guessing not, ... but I'm curious.

Comment: no i do not, but I do see it when i run it in a DOS window, but that's no surprise i suppose

Comment: Odd.  Maybe try setting the "Run the post-build event" option to "Always".

Comment: no go, it just puzzles me what is different running in VS vs. a DOS window

Comment: I presume you meant "VS2008". If there's a "VS2007", then please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that on a 64 bit system, %programfiles% needs to be replaced with

```
%ProgramW6432% or %ProgramFiles(x86)%
```

Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: sorry, i did not mention that i am on a 64 bit OS

Comment: It's curious that no error occurred.  I thought about the 32-bit versus 64-bit issue ... but I was thinking it should have showed some kind of error if it didn't like the binary.  Anyway, +1 for following up and reporting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running under Vista, Win7 or Win 2008 and UAC is making Visual Studio run in a non-admin context ? And you are launching the command prompt with admin privileges ?

Comment: I am logged in as Administrator, on Windows 2008 R2 Server, so yes, when I open a DOS command window, that is who i am, are you thinking it is not the same when I am running in VS? What is UAC?

Comment: UAC is User Access Control, it is a way of reducing your privileges even when you are an admin. If an action requires admin privileges, a pop-up asks you if you're the one who triggered the action; its purpose is to prevent malware from acting on your behalf, without you noticing.
If think that on Win2K8 R2, a command prompt is run with UAC turned off so gacutil runs fine. Try right-clicking on your VS shortcut and find 'runs as admin', select it and try again.

Comment: tried and no go, I right clicked and chose "Run as Administrator", I did not do anything with UAC, should I look into that?

Comment: No, I think I was wrong. If UAC were on, it should have prompted you if you "want to allow the following program to make changes to this computer" with a title of "User Access Control".
Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You might need double quotes around the target:  `"$(TargetPath)"`

Comment: If your path had no spaces in it, then I guess it wouldn't make any difference.  And come to think of it, if there were spaces I think you would have seen an error in the output.